# Ubuntu hardisk partition? [using gparted]

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning

as long as i know, when i tried to re size home partition, i have to position unused space to the left, but i got few full partition which contains important files, can i just move it directly to re size it for home partition?

last time i did, i deleted swap partition to let my home partition being re sized, cause it was in the right hand side of my home partition. so then i could re size it. but i have another unused space next to another filled partition, i could not erase it, cause contains important files.

How can i do it then? please help.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have worded the question makes it difficult to understand.  You may want to clean up what you are asking.

When you resize a partition, the unused space needs to be at the END of the drive - this would normally be the right - not left.  This is because things like file indexes are stored at the beginning of the partition.

You may be able to move partitions arround from a boot disk using gparted (rather then a live system running off the disk you are trying to operate on).  You should back up your data before attempting to do this though, as there is some risk.

You should also check if you are using LVM - if you are using LVM you may be able to create additional partitions and then merge them together using logical volumes.

Comment: thanks tho, and sorry for confusing you too. i am going to try LVM to do this. speaking of which, i already had a backup once before.